# How to download .json file using AFNetworking library in iOS Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, web-services, afnetworking

I am new to iOS app development. I am stuck in downloading .json file from  Amazon. I referred the following links in stackoverflow and lot more ([Using AFNetworking to Download File in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19410490/using-afnetworking-to-download-file-in-ios), [How to download the large amount of data using AFNetworking Library to show the better performance in ios?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29011678/how-to-download-the-large-amount-of-data-using-afnetworking-library-to-show-the)) but they were of no help for me.

I have a file with .json extension that has a json structured data in it. On calling the URL I want the contents of the file. I used NSURLConnection and it worked. But I want to make it work using AFNetworking.

NSURLConnection working code:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://someamazon-url/folder/file.json"]];    NSURLConnection *connection;
connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{
  NSLog(@"response received");
  self.responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}


-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{

[self.responseData appendData:data];

}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
NSDictionary *results =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.responseData options:kNilOptions error:nil];
NSLog(@"%@", results);
}
```

AFNetwork code not working:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"]; ///@"application/json"
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
```

I know there is some mistake in above code.. Kindly guide me where am I going wrong? The above code works for all other webservices. But since this is a file I am not getting what the mistake is... Please help... I have tried a lot and nothing is working

Comment: In the `GET:` method from  `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`, do you get an error there? What's the block called ? `failure`, then what does say the `error` parameter?

Comment: Sorry for not posting the error message:    failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
         {
             NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
         }];                                                                                                                Error in log is:- NSUnderlyingError=0x16d8daf0 "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: application/xml"

Comment: Your error is based on how your json-server works. Sometime your server doesn't accept your request because of something. Could you show your link? I'm sure I'm able to write code with `AFNetworking` with your link

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer..

I tried the below code and it worked,

```
NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://someamazon-url/folder/file.json"]];
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                       options:kNilOptions
                                                       error:nil];
```

I just executed these three lines and it worked.. But I dont know how far it is the right method of doing. But in this case since it is just a file i think it is fine..

Please post a comment if you think it is not the right method..

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line `[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];`

by this

```
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

Still not work then remove below line from code for this particular webservice

```
manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
```